# Passing fields to function. PYTHON.Pandas

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, try-catch

I am trying to ping an function and pass multiple fields from the dataframe pyrecords.
Unfortunately the code below gives me the correct answer for the review field, but also print all values for dealid and userid.

```
  for review in pyrecords['review']:
       analyze_text(review,u'english',pyrecords['dealid'],pyrecords['userid'])
```

Here's what the dataframe looks like.

```
>>> pyrecords
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 433 entries, 0 to 432
Data columns (total 5 columns):
createddate        433  non-null values
userid             433  non-null values
dealid             433  non-null values
preferredlocale    42  non-null values
review             433  non-null values
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2), object(2)
```

Comment: You haven't really explained what the issue is. We have no idea what the analyze_text function is doing so it's impossible to say if there's a problem. You give specific reviews to it one by one and you also give it all the dealids and userids (which seems a bit weird).

Comment: That last part, "You give specific reviews to it one by one and you also give it all the dealids and userids (which seems a bit weird)." is what i need help with, i need to pass the fields for that same row, not all the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for index, row in pyrecords.iterrows():     
    analyze_text(row['review'], u'english',row['dealid'],row['userid'])
```

Note that iterating through rows of a DataFrame may be a sign that you are not leveraging Pandas to full advantage. For better performance, you'd want to rewrite `analyze_text` to operate on a full DataFrame, or Series, instead of row-by-row.

Comment: I am getting an error with this, the review field is a str:   

   ' File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
    TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str'

Comment: @RomainD: Sorry, my fault. `iterrows` returns tuples of `(index, row)`, not just the row itself. I've edited my post to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but you seem to be trying to apply a function to each row of the DataFrame. Try

```
 analyze_english = lambda review, dealid, userid: \
     analyze_text(review, u'english', dealid, userid)

 pyrecords[['review', 'dealid', 'userid']].apply(analyze_english, axis=1)
```